# p:dataTable AutoComplete and ColumnToggler combination

Tags: primefaces, datatable

When using **autoComplete** and **columnToggler** within a dataTable, I get a broken column-list in the column toggler.
That means, the column-list doesn't show the column-names but some **javascript code instead** (for each column).

[image: columnToggler + autoComplete problem]

Here is an example:

```
<p:commandButton id="showColsButton" type="button" value="Show Columns" />
<p:columnToggler datasource="myDataTable" trigger="showColsButton" />

<p:dataTable id="myDataTable" var="row" ...>
    <p:column sortBy="#{row.myCol1}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <div><h:outputText value="My Column 01" /></div>
            <p:autoComplete ...>
                <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="myDataTable" />
            </p:autoComplete>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{row.myCol1}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Is this a bug or is there any solution for this specific problem?

Comment: Why do you put an autocomplete in the header? Put it in the filter facet and it will work!\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting an input in the header facet is not valid. If you want to use it as a filter or something, put it in a `f:facet name="filter"`.

```
<p:dataTable id="myDataTable" var="row" ...>
    <p:column filterBy="#{row.myCol1}" sortBy="#{row.myCol1}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <div><h:outputText value="My Column 01" /></div>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="filter">
            <p:autoComplete ...>
                <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="myDataTable" />
            </p:autoComplete>
        </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{row.myCol1}" />
</p:column>
```

But you might need to improve on the way the filter is used by not using the `p:ajax` but use an `onchange=PF('dataTableWidget').filter()`, adding a widgetVar attribute and adding filter attributes

**See also**

- [PrimeFaces showcase dataTable filter](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml)

Comment: Good Idea, I had a lack of knowledge concerning facet name "filter". But I can't see the autocomplete-input-box now...

Comment: 'improved' answer.

Comment: Well, since I could not see the autocomplete input box, I activated the Attribute "filterBy" (for the column), but then the "completeMethod" does not fire - that's my current problem.

Comment: That effectively is a new question... Please post one with a [mcve] (and also post version info). This answer is the answer to the 'visibile javascript' problem in the question (it happens with other components to when put in the header)

Comment: What a bogus failure (two comments ago, concerning "completeMethod does not fire")!!
I cleaned / refreshed my project and it suddenly worked - unbelievable!

Comment: Finally the facet named "filter" solved my problem. Thanks a lot!